# ReferenceError: facebook is not defined : can't connect with facebook login React Native

Tags: react-native, facebook-login

Im starting with React native and i tried to use expo-facebook to connect users (im following a tutoriel on youtube)

in the end a get this message : ReferenceError: facebook is not defined

**AuthScreen
../user/jobs/screen/users/AuthScreen.js:10
7 | // create a component
8 | const AuthScreen = (props) => {
9 |

> 10 |        facebook = async () => {
> 11 |     const {type, token}  =   await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync("xxxx", {
> 12 |                                                             permission:"public_profile"
> 13 |                                                         })**

this is the code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
 
const AuthScreen = (props) => {

       facebook = async () => {
    const {type, token}  =   await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync("xxxx", {
                                                            permission:"public_profile"
      
      })
      
       if(type == "success"){
           const credential =  firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)

           firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
           .catch(error => {
               console.log(error)
           })
       }

       props.navigation.navigate('Jobs')

       }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text  style={{fontSize: 35, textAlign:'center', paddingBottom:8}}>{`Find Jobs or \nSubmit Jobs`}</Text>
         <View style={{paddingHorizontal:30, marginTop:10}} >
             <Button title="Login with Facebook" onPress={facebook} />
         </View>
        </View>
    );
}; 
 
export default AuthScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding let before defining facebook variable

```
let facebook  = async()=>{...}
```

Comment: thank you it work and page is loaded but i get another :/